# New e-mail notifications and user-side filters

Tags: notifications, exchange

Does the built-in email application create a new e-mail notification if the e-mail is moved to another folder by a filter?

In particular, imagine the following scenario:

1. E-mail arrives at an Exchange server
2. The e-mail is pulled by an Android device.
3. The e-mail is pulled at the same time by a laptop running Outlook.
4. A program on the laptop magically moves the e-mail to a spam folder.

Imagine that steps 3 and 4 take almost no time. Also consider that step 2 may happen after steps 3 and 4.

Will the Android device create a new e-mail notification even though the e-mail is not in the Inbox?

Device Details:

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus for Verizon Wireless
- Model number SCH-I515
- SKU SCHI515MSB
- Obtained directly from Google
- ClockworkMod 6.0.3.3 recovery
- Rooted and unlocked
- Android version 4.2.2
- Baseband version I515.10 V.EK05 / I515.EK02
- Kernel version 3.0.31-cyanogenmod-ge14e5fe build03@cyanogenmod #1 Thu Jul 11 20:37:31 PDT 2013
- CPU ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7)
- Memory 693 MB
- CyanogenMod version 10.1.2-toro
- Build date Thu Jul 11 20:3159 PDT 2013
- Build number cm_toro-userdebug 4.2.2 JDQ39E eng.jenkins.20130711.203112 test-keys

Email program:

- Name: "Email"
- Version: 4.1

Exchange services:

- Name: "Exchange Services"
- version 5.0

Gmail:

- Version 4.5.2-714156

I hope this is enough information; I have leaned towards providing more rather than less because I can always edit out things later.

Comment: Android will create no alerts at all for your email. The mail app might do, however. Sorry for the hair-splitting, but the reason is: That depends very much on the mail app used, as different mail apps might handle this differently.

Comment: I've clarified that I'm referring to the default Email application.

Comment: A little better, yes -- but still not specific enough, as you don't name your device. Manufacturers tend to use their own specific apps, so there's no such thing like *the* default email app per se.